# Algebra: $(2^{k+1} − 1) + 2^{k+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Could someone explain the following bit of algebra? I'm working from a more advanced textbook (discrete math), and I think it may have skipped a few steps in explaining the algebra here. I especially don't understand the jump from line 1 to line 2.

```
(2^(k+1) − 1) + 2^(k+1) 
= 2·2^(k+1) − 1 
= 2^(k+2) − 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{k+1} -1 + 2^{k+1}$

$= 2^{k+1} + 2^{k+1} − 1$

Taking $2^{k+1}$ common from first two terms,

$= 2^{k+1}(1+1) − 1$

$= 2^{k+1}(2) − 1$

$= 2^{k+1}(2)^1 − 1$

$= 2^{k+2} − 1$

Comment: Hope its clear to you now. If still any doubt let me know.

Comment: this is clear and makes sense. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
(2^{k+1} − 1) + 2^{k+1}
&= 2^{k+1} + 2^{k+1} − 1  \\
&= 2·2^{k+1} − 1 \\
&= 2^{k+2} − 1
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\text{Rearrange.}\\
&\text{There are two factors of $2^{k+1}$.}\\
&\text{$a^m a^n = a^{m+n}$}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Still confused, but would it be correct to say: 2^(k+1) + 2^(k+1) = 4^(k+1) = 2*2^(k+1)?

Comment: I think you should consider picking up a textbook on college algebra. There are loads of such textbooks, available for dirt cheap at, say, Half Price Books. Having one of them handy might be good for these sorts of questions.

Comment: No that would not be correct. For instance, forget the exponent $k+1$. Just consider this: $2^3 + 2^3$. Is this equal to $4^3$? Let's see: $2^3 + 2^3 = 8+8 = 16$, while $4^3 = 64$. So nope. You should try to review the laws of exponents.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm aware of the laws of exponents and had reviewed them prior to posting, but was hoping for an explanation of how they apply to this particular problem.

Comment: @riley $a+a=2\cdot a\,$, so $2^{k+1}+2^{k+1}=2 \cdot 2^{k+1} = 2^{k+2}\,$.